# Android Watch Face TextClock

Tags: android, wear-os

I have an Android Watch Face that works for 12-hour formats. I am confused how to implement a 24-hour format based on the system preference of the phone, using TextClock or any other method.

```
SimpleDateFormat twelvehour = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.US);
String TimeAmPmNoSec = String.format("%s", twelvehour.format(cal.getTime()));
canvas.drawText(TimeAmPmNoSec, (centerX - (timeXLength / 2.0f ), timeYOffset, timePaint);
```

Answer (score 2):

That setting is bridged from your phone to the watch automatically and you can get it on your watch app by calling `DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; based on the result of that call, decide whether you want to use a 12HourFormat or 24HrFormat (defined similarly to what you have there).

Comment: I am not sure how i use DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context) in my code.

Comment: String formatString = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context) ? "H:mm" : "h:mm a";

and then use that in your SimpleDateFormat constructor.

Comment: The watch is able to recognize when it is 24-hr or 12-hr. However it only changes when the watch face is chosen. If i change on my phone from 12-hr to 24-hr format, the watch stays in 12-hr format until i change the watch face to something else and then back to the watch face, or when I reinstall the watch face it goes to the correct format. It does not change real time.

Comment: Should I leave it like this, since the user is unlikely to change the time format, or is there a way to change the format real time